# Persistência em Cascata JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Estou tentando realizar uma persistência em cascata utilizando JPA.

Tenho a entidade:  Course e Module

- 1 Course pode ter vários Module

  ```
  @Entity(name = "course")

  public class Course extends BaseEntity {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id_course")
  private Long idCourse;

  @SerializedName("Modules")
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = false)
  private List<Module> modules;
  ```
- 1 Module pode ter apenas um Course

  ```
  @Entity(name = "module")
  public class Module extends BaseEntity {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id_module")
  private Long idModule;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_course")
  private Course course;
  ```

Quero que no momento que for salvo o Course ele salve todos os "filhos - Module". Como está hoje, está persistindo os dois de maneira correta. Porém na tabela module o campo `id_course` está ficando como nulo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente pq o course esta nulo

```
@OneToOne(cascade= {{CascadeType.DETACH})
@JoinColumn(name = "id_course")
private Course course;
```

Preencha ele antes de salvar

```
for (Module  m : course.getModules()) {
    m.setCourse(course);
}
```

Comment: Ótimo Weslley acredito que seja exatamente isso... Estou preenchendo esse objeto com o GSON. Após esse procedimento, vou tentar realizar esse passo adicional para ver se resolve o problema.

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, funcionou perfeitamente!!!